# Open a USB stream in julia

Tags: julia

How does one open up a stream to a USB port using Julia?

I would like to do something like:

`stream = open(bus=6, device=2)`

or

`stream = open(id="1d6b:0002")`

Thank you

Comment: If you're in Linux, have you tried opening the file under /dev that corresponds to the port? I've no idea if this will work but it's what I would try.

Comment: Does [`SerialPorts.jl`](https://github.com/sjkelly/SerialPorts.jl) do what you need?

Comment: you can use PyCall to import PyUSB library from Python.  import PyCall;
usb = PyCall.pyimport("usb"); https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/58258/usb-library-for-julia-language/58260#58260